# Java stack queue getting number of people who can view the front

Tags: java, stack

I have a program that simulate queues whereby there are two types of input `join` and `leave`.

The `join` input is appended with an integer, denoting a person's height like `join 180`, while the `leave` input is appended with an integer, denoting the number of people leaving the queue `leave 3`.

Each time a join or leave query is called, the program should return the number of people who can view the front of the queue. A person can see the front if everyone in the queue in front of him/her is shorter than him/her, or if he/she is the first person in the queue.

An example of the input/output is as shown.

[image]

This is my code, i created two stacks to store the number of people in the queue, and the number of people who can view the front:

```
 private void run() {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int no_queries = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

        for(int i = 0; i < no_queries; i++){
            String[] queries = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
            int value = Integer.parseInt(queries[1]);
            switch(queries[0]){
                    case "join":
                        if(!height.empty()){
                            if(height.peek() < value){
                                height.add(value);
                            }
                        }else{
                            height.add(value);
                        }
                        stack.add(value);
                        System.out.println(height.size());
                    break;
                    case "leave":
                        for(int j = 0; j < value; j++){
                            stack.pop();
                            }
                        //how do i remove the height stack?
                        System.out.println(height.size());
                    break;
            }
        }
    }
```

This is my output, the last three entries are wrong:

```
1
0
1
1
1
2
3
2
2
0
1
0
```

My issue lies with the height stack. When the `leave 3` query is given, the integers `160`, `170` and `165` is removed from the queue stack.

However, the height stack only contains two integer `160` and `170` and both values will be removed by the query despite the fact that the person with the height `160` should not be removed from the queue as he is in front and not part of the 3 that leave.

I considered using a Person object to store the tallest person variable, but is there a more elegant way of solving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use a Person object, not to store the tallest person, but to make it possible to compare values from both stacks. I mean, when you do `stack.pop();` you need a way to check if you removed the highest person object from your stack, and if so, remove it from the stack of highest persons too.

```
static class Person {
    int height;
    Person (int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }
}

private static void run() {
    Stack<Person> stack = new Stack<>();
    Stack<Person> highest = new Stack<>();
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int n = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        String[] queries = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        int value = Integer.parseInt(queries[1]);
        switch (queries[0]) {
            case "join":
                Person person = new Person(value);
                if (highest.empty()) {
                    highest.push(person);
                } else if (value > highest.peek().height) {
                    highest.push(person);
                }
                stack.push(person);
                System.out.println(highest.size());
                break;
            case "leave":
                for (int j = 0; j < value; j++) {
                    Person left = stack.pop();
                    if (left == highest.peek()) {
                        highest.pop();
                    }
                }
                System.out.println(highest.size());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's an alternate way to solve the problem.
Each element being added to the stacks are given a identifier `y_` or `n_` to denote if they are the highest in a particular stack.

```
private void run() {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    int no_queries = Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine());

    for(int i = 0; i < no_queries; i++){
        String[] queries = sc.nextLine().split(" ");
        int value = Integer.parseInt(queries[1]);
        switch(queries[0]){
                case "join":
                    if(stack.empty()){
                        stack.add(String.format("y_%d", value));
                        height.add(String.format("y_%d", value));  
                    }else{
                        if(!height.empty()){
                            if(Integer.parseInt(height.peek().substring(2)) < value){
                                stack.add(String.format("y_%d", value));
                                height.add(String.format("y_%d", value)); 
                            }else{
                                stack.add(String.format("n_%d", value));                                    
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(height.size());
                break;
                case "leave":
                    for(int j = 0; j < value; j++){
                        if(!height.empty()){
                            if(height.peek().equals(stack.pop())){
                                height.pop();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(height.size());
                break;
        }
    }
}
```